# Postfix catch-all for all domains/users and send mail to external mailserver

Tags: linux, postfix

I am configuring a mailserver that has to save all email for any domain and any user and store it in the mailfolder of one specific user. For this I have used the following configuration:

```
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual

# cat /etc/postfix/virtual 
/.*/    specificuser
```

This works perfectly, but the only issue is that I cannot send out email; I want to sent the cron output to, for example, a gmail account. The outgoing cron email is also mapped to the virtual account and saved in the mailfolder of the specific user.

I have tried making the wildcard smaller by adding a domain (e.g. `/.*@somedomain/`, but that did not do the trick. I have also tried adding an extra line to the `/etc/postfix/virtual` file:

```
/root.*/    emailaddress@gmail.com
```

But then the email is still delivered to the `specificuser` mailfolder. The address rewrite of `root@localserver` is correct the first run and rewritten to `emailaddress@gmail.com`, but then the rewrite is performed again and `emailaddress@gmail.com`is eventually mapped on the `specificuser` catchall. See the relevant logging below.

```
postfix/cleanup[399895]: maps_find: virtual_alias_maps: pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual(0,lock|fold_fix|utf8_request): root@localserver.com = emailaddress@gmail.com
postfix/cleanup[399895]: mail_addr_find: root@localserver.com -> emailaddress@gmail.com
[...]
postfix/cleanup[399895]: maps_find: virtual_alias_maps: pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual(0,lock|fold_fix|utf8_request): emailaddress@gmail.com = specificuser
postfix/cleanup[399895]: mail_addr_find: emailaddress@gmail.com -> specificuser
```

Can someone point me to the correct configuration?

Comment: "I have also tried adding an extra line" - lines are processed IN ORDER until a match is found. That line should have been at the top of the file.

Comment: @symcbean Thanks for the quick reply; I did put it at the top and the **root** email-address is mapped to the configured email-address but than that email-address is again mapped against to the virtual users file  on the **specificuser** catchall. I have added logging to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = example.com
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

According to the [Postfix documentation](https://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox), a virtual mailbox domain is a domain that does not correspond to a UNIX system account. Instead, each recipient is mapped to a virtual mailbox location of the form /path/name, where /path is a directory (for example, /var/mail/vhosts) and name is a file or directory name under /path. The virtual mailbox location can be different for each recipient in the same domain.

To enable virtual mailbox domains, you need to set the following parameters in your /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = example.com
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

The first parameter specifies the list of virtual mailbox domains that Postfix will accept mail for. You can use a comma-separated list, a hash table, or a regular expression to define the domains. In this case, you have only one domain: example.com.

The second parameter specifies the mapping of virtual mailbox recipients to their virtual mailbox locations. You need to create a file called /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox and list the recipients and their locations in the following format:

```
user1@example.com    example.com/user1
user2@example.com    example.com/user2
...
```

You can use any directory structure under /var/mail/vhosts as long as it matches the virtual mailbox locations. You need to run postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox after editing the file.

The third parameter specifies the delivery agent that will handle the mail for the virtual mailbox recipients. In this case, you are using Dovecot's LMTP server, which listens on a UNIX socket called private/dovecot-lmtp. You need to configure Dovecot to enable LMTP and set the mail location for the virtual mailboxes.

According to the [Dovecot documentation](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/protocols/lmtp_server/), you need to add the following lines to your /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf file:

```
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
}
```

And you need to add the following lines to your /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf file:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_uid = vmail
mail_gid = vmail
```

The first line tells Dovecot where to store the mail for the virtual mailboxes. It uses the same directory structure as Postfix. The %d and %n variables are replaced by the domain and user name of the recipient.

The second and third lines tell Dovecot which user and group to use for accessing the mail files. You need to create a system user and group called vmail with no login shell and no home directory, and make sure that they own the /var/mail/vhosts directory and its subdirectories.

After making these changes, you need to restart Postfix and Dovecot for them to take effect.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer; would I then use **gmail.com** as **virtual_mailbox_domains**? And what would I put in the **virtual_mailbox_maps**?

Comment: No, you need to add the domain where you you want to save the mail for. This makes sure that only for that domain the mail is saved and all other domains are handled as usually. I will update my post with some extra information

Comment: I wouldn't do it for all domains, that could be a security risk, and easily become an open relay